# Error in fetching questions for specific tag

Tags: java, stackexchange-api

I am using **stackoverflow-java-sdk** to fetch recents questions of specific tag.

But i am getting following error. I don't have clue whats wrong with it , earlier same code base was working.

```
Exception in thread "Thu May 15 21:14:45 IST 2014" com.google.code.stackexchange.client.exception.StackExchangeApiException: com.google.code.stackexchange.client.exception.StackExchangeApiException: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.query.impl.BaseStackOverflowApiQuery.list(BaseStackOverflowApiQuery.java:151)
at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.query.impl.QuestionApiQueryImpl.list(QuestionApiQueryImpl.java:188)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.google.code.stackexchange.client.exception.StackExchangeApiException: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.query.impl.BaseStackOverflowApiQuery.unmarshallObject(BaseStackOverflowApiQuery.java:208)
at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.impl.StackExchangeApiGateway.callApiMethod(StackExchangeApiGateway.java:266)
at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.impl.StackExchangeApiGateway.callApiMethod(StackExchangeApiGateway.java:233)
at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.query.impl.BaseStackOverflowApiQuery.list(BaseStackOverflowApiQuery.java:142)
... 14 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:58)
at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:84)
at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:59)
at com.google.code.stackexchange.client.query.impl.BaseStackOverflowApiQuery.unmarshallObject(BaseStackOverflowApiQuery.java:201)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:151)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1263)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1309)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.consumeNonExecutePrefix(JsonReader.java:1514)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:523)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414)
at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:42)
... 20 more
```

Comment: Well, the message tells you that the stream is closed so you might want to look for the reason why.

Comment: Thomas, you are correct , i do have same analogy. Real problem is , it is happening at SDK side,i am looking for if someone have same problem .

Comment: I don't know that API but the source for that problem might not be the SDK. The stream might get closed outside the SDK and the SDK just complains about the stream being closed prematurely or there might be another error, like a connection failure, which causes the stream to be closed.

Comment: Sure Thomas, I got your point. i will figure out and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Issue is at API end, Stack-overflow-SDK  is using API V1.0 internally, which has been shutdown from 12 May 2014.

This is causing failure to access to stackoverflow through SDK.

Please find more detail at :
https://stackapps.com/questions/3439/deprecating-api-v1-x